# To change the color for each line in android

Tags: android, colors, textview

Hi,
I used this code:

```
String displayText = "";
    try {
        InputStream fileStream = getResources().openRawResource(
                            R.raw.t);
        int fileLen = fileStream.available();
        // Read the entire resource into a local byte buffer.
        byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[fileLen];
        fileStream.read(fileBuffer);
        fileStream.close();
        displayText = new String(fileBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // exception handling
        }

    TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(displayText);


}
```

It's for displaying a text file.
I want to change the color on each line ( and change the color of a line in between lines)
What should I do?

I'm sorry for bad speak english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use html to set the colors in your textview. A small example that swaps between 2 colors:

```
String textcontent = ""; 
String[] lines;
//something like "lines = displayText.split("\n")" or however you stored line returns
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    //odd line numbers are red, the even ones green
    textcontent += "<font color=\"" + (i%2==0?"red":"green") + "\">" + lines[i] + "</font><br/>";
}
TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(textcontent));
```

I hope this helped, otherwise feel free to ask for more...

Comment: & i can use custom font,in this way?

Comment: Sure, something like face=\"Georgia\" should do the trick. Check out [this info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp) for more about the font-tag, some other html tags also work though..
Happy coding =)